# meteor js and facebook site url , login from different IP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I am using facebook-accounts to log in to my meteor app.

I have 2 devices, desktop and a mobile.

On my desktop i am running my meteor app.

On my facebook app, i have set the Site URL to `http://localhost:3000/`

I can successfully login in from my desktop.

**BUT**
On my mobile, i can not.

**So What i did**
is set the Site URL to `http://192.168.1.5:3000/`, which is my desktop ip address
Now i cant sign in from desktop or mobile. Its all to do with the callback URL.

How can i set up my system so i can use facebook login from different IP address. In production obviously i don't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook app, you give **comma separated multiple domains** if you want.

-> Go to Developer page at following URL -

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

-> then go to Your app

-> Go to Settings tab on left

-> then in Site URL input box, you give domains list in comma separated format

-> Click Save and done.

Comment: I did add localhost and also the ip in the site url sperated by command. still doesnt solve the issue. and now i cant event authenticate becuase it says "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not "

Comment: In Callback URL, add both the URL, if it shows warning, replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 and remove trailing "/" at the end of callback url.

Answer (score 0):

For testing you should keep Site URL to http://localhost:3000 and Mobile URL to http://ip_address:3000

The catch here is that ip_address (you metioned 192.168.1.5) would probably be a dynamic IP address and you would need to change it in the App settings on FB developers site everytime your dev machine's IP address changes.

You could also try to configure your router to give your machine a permanent IP address.